# customed message for a specific person via GCM(google cloud messaging)

Tags: python, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

just I want to ask you about **GCM technology**,I have to use it for my client in his application(college application). So my question : Is it possible to send a message for someone let's say a professor working in that college(Hi Sir, please you have to be present in administration today at 9 Am), of course as I said just for **one professor** not all the users application !!!

my idea here is to pick the specific professor from the listview of all persons in that college (by fetching the database) and send to him my message as **push information**  . 
just I want to note that I'm using **python** as **backend language** and **Android** as **client**

Is my idea valid or should I see another way ???
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to send a notification to a single device on which the app is installed. Each device is assigned a registration ID when your app registers to GCM on that device. If you send this registration ID along with some identifier that identifies the user of the app on that device (the professor in your case), your server will be able to send messages to specific users.

Comment: thanks a lot Eran but I need just one question: can I develop the process of sending the message it means without using the standard dashboard of the GCM.Because my client want to do that in one operation:just a click on the name of the client(the professor) and he insert his message.Then with one click on the sending button : the message will be on his way to the professor!!!
Can I make my own button (for example a simple html button )????

Comment: I don't know what "standard dashboard" you are talking about. There is no standard dashboard for sending GCM messages. You can develop whatever web form you want with whatever buttons you need, and program it to send a message however you like.